# What's the difference between a Job and a Daemon?

Tags: services

I currently am a bit confused with all the terms Linux has for running software.

Now these new term *job* has appeared. 
What is a *job*?

It's also a process (running software)? Right?

But especially:

**What's the difference between a job and a daemon?**

They both seem to be background programs with no user interface. So in what do they differ?

Comment: A job is a task that runs until it's finished, i.e. it has no more work to do. A daemon is a background process, such as a server, that runs until someone, typically an administrator, tells it to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A job is any program that you interactively start and that does not detach itself.

The are a couple of commands for job control:

```
jobs - List all the jobs that are running or suspended.
fg - Bring the job to the foreground.
bg - Send the job to the background.
stop or Ctrl + z - Suspend the job.
kill or Ctrl + c - Terminate the job.
```

When you append " &" at the end of the command it becomes a "background job".

Jobs tend to end at some point.

A daemon is a process that runs detached from your session. So basically something you/we do not have direct control over. It waits for something to react upon (so when an event happens or a condition is met). Daemons tend to end when you stop them or when the system is shutdown. Where you can start them again manually or during booting.

Comment: Some people say _daemon_ is an acronym for _Disk And Execution MONitor_. While this definition is questionable, the _monitor_ part still holds: _daemons_ often monitor something (like a socket) and act upon it (by returning a response). To do so, they often run always (like MySQL, Apache). After all, the acronym is a good mnemonic to remember whether it is spelled _daemon_ or _deamon_.